# xslt to multiple output and base output directory

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, saxon

the xsl code is the following

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/t:Flow/t:AccountingRecords/t:AccountingRecord">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="UBL-invoice.2.1-{t:Reference}-output.xml">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

My code is quite the one from the samples

```
Processor proc = new Processor();
var comp = proc.NewXsltCompiler();
Xslt30Transformer exe = comp.Compile(new Uri("file:///" + System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("./Styles/style.xslt"))).Load30();

var baseOutUri = new System.Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
exe.BaseOutputURI = baseOutUri.AbsoluteUri;
Console.WriteLine(exe.BaseOutputURI);

DocumentBuilder builder = proc.NewDocumentBuilder();
builder.BaseUri = new Uri("file:///" + System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("./ar2.xml"));

XdmNode inp = builder.Build(System.IO.File.OpenRead(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("./ar2.xml")));

Serializer serializer = proc.NewSerializer();
serializer.SetOutputWriter(Console.Out);

// Transform the source XML and serialize the result document
exe.ApplyTemplates(inp, serializer); // < ==== Exception here
```

The `Console.WriteLine` writes:

> file:///D:/dev/fromSvn/cclb/bas/bin/debug

But the outputs are generated in:

> D:\dev\fromSvn\cclb\bas\bin

If I want to fix this I have to modify my code to:

```
exe.BaseOutputURI = baseOutUri.AbsoluteUri + "/";
```

M'I correct or do I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way URI resolution works. If the base URI is `/a/b/c`, and the relative URI is `w.xml`, then the result of resolving the relative URI against the base URI is `/a/b/w.xml`. The algorithm for resolving a relative URI is a syntactic operation on two character strings, it never attempts to work out whether the base URI `/a/b/c` refers to a directory, to an ordinary file, or to nothing in particular.